# Easy way to create perforce changelist with multiple filespecs

Tags: version-control, perforce, changelist

I wish to submit a changelist with multiple filespecs, e.g. ...this... ...file.h ...theother....  Perforce won't let me.  I could create a changelist from a file but I do want a chance to review the files and enter the comment.  This is for a command-line solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a pending changelist, then move all the files you want into that, before submitting it. Even from the command-line, although I find p4V easier to use for this functionality.

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/change.html#1040665

```
p4 change
```

to create a pending changelist.

```
p4 reopen
```

to move files into the pending changelist.

Comment: `p4 change -o` and `p4 change -i` would be required in order to avoid using an editor -

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for a UNIX/*NIX command line solution, this will give you a new, clean changelist and keep the number in `$cl`:

```
export cl=`p4 change -o | grep '^\(Change\|Client\|User\|Description\)' | p4 change -i | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an endlessly frustrating problem.  You should be able to create a p4 changelist from the Windows command line without invoking the editor by doing:

```
p4 change -o 
    | findstr /C:Description: /C:Change: /C:Client: /C:User: /C:Status: 
    | p4 change -i
```

The return string will be something like "Change 1500 created." which you can parse for the changelist.  You could then add individual filespecs by doing:

```
p4 edit -c 1500 //depot/base/...files.c
```

Or something along those line.  The relatively significant problem with this solution is the inability to modify the description.  Alternatively, you can create a temp file with the requisite Description, Change, Client, etc strings and create the changelist via:

```
p4 change -i < tempfile.txt
```

This seems somewhat sloppier but may be the best alternative for scripting solutions.

Comment: This is a little simpler:p4 change -o | findstr /v "enter description here" | p4 change -i

Answer (score 5):

Based on Michael Gilbert's answer, you can edit the description in powershell like so:

```
$newCLFormat = p4 change -o | select-string -pattern change, client, status
$newCLFormat += "Description: " + $myDescription
$newCLFormat | p4 change -i
```

To pull out the new changelist number:

```
$newCLFormat | p4 change -i | select-string "\b(\d)+" | %{$_.matches[0].value}
```

Now there's got to be a quicker, neater way to pull out that number?

edit: refactored findstr to select-string

edit: neater way to retrieve the changelist:

```
$newCLFormat | p4 change -i | %{ $_.split()[1] }
```

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this question today, and @Martin's answer was very helpful. I wanted to create a changelist with a description instead of leaving it blank, so I used his command as a starting point and tweaked it into this:

```
export cl=`p4 change -o | sed 's/<enter description here>/"Change list description"/' | sed '/^#/d' | sed '/^$/d' | p4 change -i | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
```

Comment: This worked great for me in *NIX, bash v4.1. One thing I noticed, there's a trailing space at the end, and I can't tell where it's coming from.. '"Change list description" '

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner that works in the Windows cmd shell with just p4 command line and the Windows-standard findstr utility and doesn't need any temporary files.

```
(p4 change -o | findstr /v "enter description here" & echo ○My new changelist)|p4 change -i
```

This will:

- generate a changelist specification ("p4 change -o")
- remove the "enter description here" line ("findstr -v")
- append your new description ("echo")
- and finally create the new changelist ("p4 change -i")

Note that the description must start with a tab character, which is that little "○" guy. If the formatting breaks en route to your shell, you can type a tab character with Alt-9.

Comment: I´ve tried with a clean default changelist and works perfectly, but if I have any files already on the list it gives me the next error. Error in change specification.
Can't include file(s) not already opened.
Open new files with p4 add, p4 edit, etc. Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like the newest command line interface supports a new `--field` option that would be useful here. You could probably use this to set the Description to your text and the Files list to empty, then use `p4 reopen` to move the files into your new changelist. More info: https://www.perforce.com/blog/160428/20161-command-line-roundup

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is my rough first pass at a Perl wrapper around p4 commands.
It would be most useful if you had a LOT of files to check in.
The form editor is NOT invoked.

#
# p4checkoutfiles.pl -
#
#       Will check out all files in current directory.
#       Print newly-created changelist number to display, for p4submitfiles.pl.
#       Optional command line parameter for Description, e.g. "Modifications from 07/25/2011".
#
#     USAGE:
#         1. Copy this script to a new folder.
#         2. Copy all files to be checked in to this same folder.
#         3. Run this script to check out all the files, as follows:
#
#               p4checkoutfiles.pl  <clientspec> <changelist_description>
#
#           For example:
#
#               p4checkoutfiles.pl ClientSpec-Mike "Modifications from 07/25/2011".
#
#
#         4. Manually copy these files over their older versions, in the correct workspace directory.
#         5. Run p4checkinfiles.pl.
#
# 

use strict;
use warnings;

################################################################################
# Save any command line parameters in local variables.
################################################################################

my $Client = shift;
die unless $Client;

my $ChangelistDescription = shift;


################################################################################
# Read default p4 form from pipe that executes p4 change command.
################################################################################

my $DefaultChangelistForm = "";

my $PrintDefaultChangelistCommand = "p4 change -o |";

open (PRINTDEFAULTCHANGELISTCOMMAND, $PrintDefaultChangelistCommand);

while (<PRINTDEFAULTCHANGELISTCOMMAND>)
{
    if (($_ !~ "Client") &&
        ($_ !~ "User") &&
        ($_ !~ "Status"))
    {
        $DefaultChangelistForm .= $_;
    }
}

# print "\$DefaultChangelistForm is: " . $DefaultChangelistForm; 

close PRINTDEFAULTCHANGELISTCOMMAND;



################################################################################
# Swap in any command line parameter for Description
################################################################################

if ($ChangelistDescription)
{
    $DefaultChangelistForm =~ s/<enter description here>/$ChangelistDescription/
}


################################################################################
# Write modified form values to disk, to be read by following p4 change -i.
################################################################################

open (FORMFORNEWCHANGELIST, ">formfornewchangelist.txt");
print FORMFORNEWCHANGELIST $DefaultChangelistForm;
close (FORMFORNEWCHANGELIST);



################################################################################
# Create new changelist using FORMFORNEWCHANGELIST.
# Read new changelist number from pipe that creates new changelist.
################################################################################

print "Creating new changelist...\n";

my $NewChangeList = "";
my $NewChangeListNumber = "";

my $CreateNewChangeListCommand = "";

$CreateNewChangeListCommand = "p4 -c ";
$CreateNewChangeListCommand .= $Client;
$CreateNewChangeListCommand .= " change -i < formfornewchangelist.txt |";

open (CREATENEWCHANGELISTCOMMAND, $CreateNewChangeListCommand);

while (<CREATENEWCHANGELISTCOMMAND>)
{
    if ($_ =~ "created")
    {
        # Save new change list number for below.
        $NewChangeListNumber = $_;
        print $_;
    }
}

close CREATENEWCHANGELISTCOMMAND;

################################################################################
# Save new changelist number to disk file newchangelistnumber.txt.
################################################################################

# Just parse numbers from string.
if ($NewChangeListNumber =~ /(\d+)/)
{
    $NewChangeListNumber = $1;
}


open (NEWCHANGELISTNUMBER, ">newchangelistnumber.txt");
print NEWCHANGELISTNUMBER $NewChangeListNumber;
close (NEWCHANGELISTNUMBER);


################################################################################
# Read workspace root from pipe that executes p4 client command.
################################################################################

my $WorkspaceRoot = "";

my $PrintClientCommand = "p4 client -o ";
$PrintClientCommand .= $Client;
$PrintClientCommand .= " |";

open (PRINTCLIENTCOMMAND, $PrintClientCommand);

while (<PRINTCLIENTCOMMAND>)
{
    # Save workspace root for edit command, below.
    if ($_ =~ "Root:")
    {
        $WorkspaceRoot = $_;

        # Just parse stuff after Root:
        if ($WorkspaceRoot =~ /Root:\s*(.*)/)
        {
            $WorkspaceRoot = $1;
        }
    }
}
close PRINTCLIENTCOMMAND;

die unless length($WorkspaceRoot) > 0;
# print "WorkspaceRoot is: " . $WorkspaceRoot;


################################################################################
# For each file (other than newchangelistnumber.txt),
# check out that file into newly-created changelist.
# NOTE: THIS CODE ASSUMES THE FILES HAVE ALREADY BEEN ADDED TO PERFORCE.
# Enhancement: Fix above constraint.
################################################################################

print "Checking out all files in this subdirectory already in Perforce...\n";

my $directory = '.';
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
while (my $file = readdir(DIR))
{
    # We only want files
        next unless (-f "$directory/$file");

    # Skip text files.
    next if ($file =~ m/\.txt$/);

    # Skip Perl files.
        next if ($file =~ m/\.pl$/);

    my $CheckOutFileCommand = "";

    $CheckOutFileCommand = "p4 -c ";
    $CheckOutFileCommand .= $Client;
    $CheckOutFileCommand .= " edit ";
    $CheckOutFileCommand .= " -c " . $NewChangeListNumber . " ";
    $CheckOutFileCommand .= $WorkspaceRoot . "\\" . $file;
    $CheckOutFileCommand .= " | ";

    open (CHECKOUTFILECOMMAND, $CheckOutFileCommand);

    while (<CHECKOUTFILECOMMAND>)
    {
        print $_;
    }

    close CHECKOUTFILECOMMAND;

}

closedir(DIR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
p4 submit
```

If your P4EDITOR is vim, then you will get a vim edit window. Goto command mode and select all the lines after the line "Files:"  by typing

```
v followed by PgDown until you're done selecting all the files
```

Then do

```
:g!/.*pattern1.*#/d
```

If you have multiple patterns like this,

```
:g!/.*pattern1.*#\|.*pattern2.*#\|.*pattern3.*#/d etc...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am looking for a command line implementation for use in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation for Maya (MEL):

```
proc string jp_newChangeList()
{
    //This will return the file format as a string
    string $changelist = `system("p4 change -o || p4 change -i")`;
    //Break up the string by line
    string $breakChange[]; tokenize $changelist "\n" $breakChange;
    //Find the line called "enter description here" and edit it with your text (precede text with 4 SPACES to preserve format!!!)
    int $count = 0;
    int $mine = 0;
    for($lii in $breakChange)
    {
        $lii = `strip $lii`;
        if($lii == "<enter description here>") $mine = $count;
        $count++;
    }
    $breakChange[$mine] = "    User enters text for description here";
    //get a local dummy file location and call it "p4.txt". We will use this to generate a changelist
    $exampleFileName = ( `internalVar -userTmpDir` + "p4.txt" );
    $fileId=`fopen $exampleFileName "w"`;
    int $printCount = 0;
    //Print string array, one line at a time, until you pass the description string (leaving the "files" part unspecified)
    while($printCount <= $mine)
    {
        fprint $fileId ($breakChange[$printCount] + "\n");
        $printCount++;
    }
    //close the text file
    fclose $fileId;
    //Read the text file to return the changelist number 
    string $changelist = `system("p4 change -i < " + $exampleFileName)`;
    //Parse return statement to isolate changelist number
    string $changeNum[]; tokenize $changelist " " $changeNum;
    string $changeListNumber = $changeNum[1];
    return $changeListNumber;
}
```